# Googledoc-how to update link-table (from googlesheet) on open

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I have a table that linked with my googlesheet, is there anyway that can auto-update (without click update button) the table when the doc open/refresh? I tried this but it didnt work

```
function onOpen(e){  var getdoc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();  var tables = getdoc.getTables(); tables[0].refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### There is a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/126790287) for it on Google's Public Issue Tracker

But so far, it has not been implemented yet.

I recommend you to give it a "star" to show that more users are affected and  interested in this feature.